# "Cannot set sharingModel to ControlledByParent on a CustomObject without a MasterDetail" on an "sfdx force:source:push"

Tags: master-detail, salesforcedx

Been getting the error:

> Cannot set sharingModel to ControlledByParent on a CustomObject
>   without a MasterDetail

this morning when editing/adding fields to some custom objects that are in a master-detail chain and then doing a:

```
sfdx force:source:push
```

Re-created the scratch org a couple of times to work around this. But how to work around this in a less time consuming way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based on the workaround from [Cannot set sharingModel to ControlledByParent on a CustomObject without a MasterDetail relationship field](https://clickdeploy.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/333757068095-Cannot-set-sharingModel-to-ControlledByParent-on-a-CustomObject-without-a-MasterDetail-relationship-field):

> **Workaround:**
>   
> Add the master-detail lookup field to the deployment (even
>   if it has not changed) to your deployment selected list.

it looks like the problem is that sfdx fails to push the master-detail relationship field when it doesn't change.

Until sfdx is fixed to address this, a simple workaround is to manually change e.g. the `label` of the master-detail field so it does get pushed at the same time as the other changes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomField xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fullName>Policy__c</fullName>
    <externalId>false</externalId>
    <label>Policy XXX</label>
```

and try hard to remember to change it back to the correct value straight after and do another push...

If you have a better solution please post an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Putting just a comment works as well `<!-- -->`

Comment: Automated this by adding a timestamp comment to our master detail metadata files while pushing.